# date picker to set startdate show 6 nov

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I am trying to change the start date in calendar to show the month Nov, start with date 6  and end date is 17 Feb 2018

how i adjust it i try to adjust but it not work  need help

```
 DatePicker();
  function DatePicker() {
    var apb_get_day_advance = (typeof apb_day_book != 'undefined') ? parseInt(apb_day_book) : 0;
    var date_format = (jQuery.datepicker.regional[apb_lang].dateFormat) ? jQuery.datepicker.regional[apb_lang].dateFormat : 'mm/dd/yy';
    var apb_number_of_calendar = (typeof apbAjax.apb_number_calendar != 'undefined') ? parseInt(apbAjax.apb_number_calendar) : 2;
    $('.date-start-js').datepicker({
      format: "mm/dd/yy",
      buttonImageOnly: false,

      numberOfMonths: apb_number_of_calendar,
      minDate : apb_get_day_advance,

      onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
        var $this = $(this);
        var $form = $this.closest('form');
        if ( $('.apb-format-date').length == 0 ) {
          $form.append('<input type="hidden" name="apb_formatdate" class="apb-format-date" value="' + $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat + '">');
        }
        if (selectedDate) {

          var timeConvert = new Date( $this.datepicker('getDate').getTime() );
          var number_nights = $form.find('.night-select-js').length ? parseInt( $form.find('.night-select-js').val() ) : 1;

          var $date_end = $form.find('.date-end-js');
          var date_end = new Date(timeConvert);
          date_end.setDate(date_end.getDate() + number_nights);

          $date_end.val($.datepicker.formatDate($.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat,new Date(date_end)));
          $date_end.attr("data-date",$.datepicker.formatDate('mm/dd/yy',new Date(date_end)));

          /*----------  Add Date Customize  ----------*/
          $this.attr("data-date",$.datepicker.formatDate('mm/dd/yy',new Date(timeConvert)));
          /*----------  Add Date Customize  ----------*/

          /*----------  Relationship to calendar  ----------*/
          $this.trigger('change');
          $('#apb_calendar').datepicker('refresh');
          $('#apb_calendar').datepicker('setDate', $.datepicker.formatDate( 'mm/dd/yy', new Date(timeConvert) ) );
          $('td.ui-datepicker-current-day a.ui-state-default').removeClass('ui-state-active');

          $form.find('.date-end-js').datepicker( "option", "minDate", date_end );
        }

      },
      beforeShow: function(input, inst) {
        $('#ui-datepicker-div').addClass('apb-datepicker');
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

I hope it will work for you.

You can disable previous date using javascript function, for example if you want to start date with current date & hide all previous date so you can do that using javascript function.

First give ID to your input field and then add below javascript code to your template or footer file.

```
jQuery("#field_cq59zg").datetimepicker({
   //    debug: true,
   useCurrent: false,
   format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
   locale: 'en',    
   minDate: moment('24/08/2017 00:00 AM', 'DD-MM-YYYY'),
   maxDate: moment('31/12/2020 11:59 PM', 'DD-MM-YYYY'),
   daysOfWeekDisabled: []
});
```

Comment: can i call that function in wordpress?

Comment: Yes you can call this function in wordpress, but before do this please check above javascript code, there i do some changes in code, please add this updated code.